# Clear inputs parting from index

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I have an array `betSlip`, where I am doing some validation, lets say that the array has 4 indexes right now, every index has an `input` so I have 4 inputs, one per index.

Example: Values I type in the inputs:

> 1 input: 10
>
> 2 input: 10
>
> 3 input: 10
>
> 4 input: 10

The next input can not be greater than the previous.
Which in my app means that if I go to the 2nd input and type the number 1, the inputs 3 and 4 should be back to 0 again. But as I have it in my app so far, if you type 1 in the 2nd input, ONLY the 3rd input get back to 0 and not the others.

So, to be clear: If I have 10 inputs where I typed the number 100 in every single input, and I go to the 3rd input and type 99, then the rest of the inputs should be back to 0. Except the previous inputs.

I am using Angular and also Lodash.

I took a couple pictures

[image]

In this image I typed 1 in the 2nd input, and only the 3rd input is on 0, I need every single input back in 0, parting from the current index.

[image]

and here my code:

```
$scope.riskWinCalculations2 = function(slip, type, index) {
  var previousSlip = $scope.betSlip[index - 1],
      currentSlip = $scope.betSlip[index],
      nextSlip = $scope.betSlip[index + 1];


      if (currentSlip.risk.length && nextSlip != undefined) {
        if (currentSlip.risk < nextSlip.risk) {
          nextSlip.risk = 0;
          nextSlip.win = 0;
        }
      }
}
```

I know my mistake is here in this var `nextSlip`, where all I am doing is tell the app to put an empty string in the next input if the current one is a less amount. But that is why I am here, I need to know how to solve it, taking into account all the next inputs and not only the right next input.

Also, [I made a video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=81ai2skVNZI&feature=youtu.be)

**UPDATE TO ADD MORE EXPLANATION**

if every input has 10 as a value, and you have 5 inputs, it means:

> 1 input: 10
>
> 2 input: 10
>
> 3 input: 10
>
> 4 input: 10
>
> 5 input: 10

if you go to the 3rd input and type 5, it means:

> 1 input: 10
>
> 2 input: 10
>
> 3 input: 5
>
> 4 input: 0
>
> 5 input: 0

so, as you see the other inputs get back to 0 which is the initial value. But the previous inputs keeps the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
      //if the user tries to play with the input:
      //he can not put lower amount in a previous input,
      //when the next input is already filled out
      _.each($scope.betSlip, function(slip, indexSlip) {
        if (indexSlip > index) {
          slip.risk = '';
          slip.win = '';
        }
      });
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly, I have done the above logic using `ng-repeat` and `ng-blur`. Let me know if any logic is missing.

```
<div ng-app>
  <h2>Todo</h2>
  <div ng-controller="TodoCtrl">
      <p ng-repeat='data in datas'>
          <label>{{$index+1}}</label><input  ng-model='data.value' ng-blur='checkRisk($index)'/>      
      </p>
  </div>
</div>


function TodoCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.datas = [{value:10},{value:10},{value:10},{value:10},{value:10}];   
    $scope.checkRisk = function(index){       
        for(var i=index+1;i<$scope.datas.length;i++){                
                $scope.datas[i].value=0;
            }        
    };
}
```

check jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/gopinathshiva/U3pVM/16711/

Comment: In your first input below the title ```TODO``` you have a 10 as in the other inputs. If you type ```1``` lets say in the 4th input, the other inputs parting from the 4th, should be back to ```0```, which is not happening in your example. In your example I can type anything. The current input should be equal or less than the previous.

Comment: you mentioned **rest of the inputs should turn to zero, not the previous inputs**. So I did like that

Comment: Look: ```The current input should be equal or less than the previous.``` which means: put back to 0 the other inputs parting from the current one.

Comment: means user should be restricted to input values greater than the previous ones?

Comment: right. If you have 10 in the current input, you can not put 11 in the next input, otherwise that next input should be back to 0. But I have that functionality already. The issue I am having is when the inputs are filled out, and the user decides to put a less amount in one of the inputs in the middle. As in the video.

Comment: In the video or the pics you can see that the user types 1 in one of the inputs in the middle, and only the right next input turn back to 0, and the 4th input keeps the same number. I want that all the inputs PARTING FROM THE CURRENT ONE get back to 0 :)

Comment: It is better know but I did it that way already. Try putting ```1``` in the second input, it will turn ```0``` EVERY SINGLE INPUT in your example. And the inputs should be on ```0```, but PARTING FROM the current input. So if you type ```1``` in the second input, then, the next inputs should be ```0``` also, and not the previous.